# Rails Displaying a category name from a belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to display a category name instead of a number (cat_id) from a belongs to relationship, I have cars and makes, basically here's the code -

show.html.erb

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>


<p>
  <b>Make:</b>
  <%= @car.make_id %> 
</p>

<h2>
  <em><%= @car.model %> <%= @car.body_typw %> <%= @car.engine_size %> <%= @car.trim %></em>
</h2>

<p>
  <%= image_tag @car.image(:large) %>
</p>

<% @carimages.each do |carimage| %>

    <%= image_tag carimage.image(:thumb), :class => "imgsmall" %>

<% end %>

<p>
  <b>Transmission:</b>
  <%= @car.transmission %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Fuel type:</b>
  <%= @car.fuel_type %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Millage:</b>
  <%= @car.millage %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Price:</b>
  <%= number_to_currency(@car.price) %>
</p>

<p>
  <%= raw @car.content %>
</p>
```

So basically i want the Make name here:-

```
<p>
  <b>Make:</b>
  <%= @car.make_id %> 
</p>
```

cars_controller.rb

```
class CarsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /cars
  # GET /cars.json
  def index
    @cars = Car.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @cars }
    end
  end

  # GET /cars/1
  # GET /cars/1.json
  def show
    @car = Car.find(params[:id])
    @pages = Page.all
    @carimages = Carimage.all
    @carimages = Carimage.find(:all, :limit => 10, :order => "id DESC")
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @car }
    end
  end

  # GET /cars/new
  # GET /cars/new.json
  def new
    @car = Car.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @car }
    end
  end

  # GET /cars/1/edit
  def edit
    @car = Car.find(params[:id])
  end
  # POST /cars
  # POST /cars.json
  def create
    @car = Car.new(params[:car])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @car.save
        format.html { redirect_to @car, notice: 'Car was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @car, status: :created, location: @car }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @car.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /cars/1
  # PUT /cars/1.json
  def update
    @car = Car.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @car.update_attributes(params[:car])
        format.html { redirect_to @car, notice: 'Car was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @car.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /cars/1
  # DELETE /cars/1.json
  def destroy
    @car = Car.find(params[:id])
    @car.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to cars_url }
      format.json { head :ok }
    end
  end
end
```

it is related through make table - id and car table - make_id

Thanks

Robbie

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure - the belongs to relationship gives you an object (a `Make` in your case), which you can call methods on - including getting field names!

So, If you set up your models like so:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :make
end


class Make < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

And `Make` has a field named `name`, you could in your view:

```
<p>
  <b>Make:</b>
  <%= @car.make.name %> 
</p>
```

Comment: Note that many may view this as a Law of Demeter violation, but the importance of that is up to the developer.

Comment: Yes, I thought about mentioning something like that (the delegate method that Rails gives is an interesting read sometime), but decided against it (to not complicate this matter to a Rails beginner) :)

Comment: in a similar manner i have a problem with displaying a set of images on a page and instead of displaying all i would like to display them from the current record -

<% @carimages.each do |carimage| %>
  
    <%= image_tag carimage.image(:thumb), :class => "imgsmall" %>
  
<% end %>